# Can we add users to keycloak in realms other than 'master'?

Tags: http, exception, keycloak

I can add users to keycloak but only in the master realm. Is there a way to add users to other realms beside master?

I tried and received an HTTP 401 Unauthorized Exception.

Comment: 401 while adding new users or while authenticating with new users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your user doesn't have the `manage-users` role in other realms.

Just go to the admin realm, look up your user, navigate to `Role mappings` tab, then in the `Client Roles` drop down select the correct realm and then add `manage-users` as a role. Repeat for all realms.

Comment: I don't see the manage-users role at all even in my master realm. I see the admin role, but this role doesn't seem to be available in other realms.

Comment: @user840930 Which keycloak version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

```
//Here's how I created a user to my realm using Java 

@Override
public UserDto registerNewUserAccount(final UserDto accountDto) {
    String keycloakPassword = accountDto.getPassword();

    accountDto.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(accountDto.getPassword()));
    accountDto.setEnabled(1);
    UserDto user = userRepository.save(accountDto);

    AuthorityDto role = new AuthorityDto();
    role.setUserName(accountDto.getLogin());
    role.setAuthority("ROLE_USER");

    authorityRepository.save(role);

    Keycloak kc = Keycloak.getInstance(
            "https://www.zdslogic.com/keycloak/auth",  /your server
            "zdslogic",  //your realm
            "richard.campion", //user 
            "Changit", //password
            "admin-cli"); //client


    CredentialRepresentation credential = new CredentialRepresentation();
    credential.setType(CredentialRepresentation.PASSWORD);
    credential.setValue(keycloakPassword);

    UserRepresentation keycloakUser = new UserRepresentation();
    keycloakUser.setUsername(accountDto.getLogin());
    keycloakUser.setFirstName(accountDto.getFirstName());
    keycloakUser.setLastName(accountDto.getLastName());
    keycloakUser.setEmail(accountDto.getEmail());
    keycloakUser.setCredentials(Arrays.asList(credential));
    keycloakUser.setEnabled(true);
    keycloakUser.setRealmRoles(Arrays.asList("user"));

    // Get realm
    RealmResource realmResource = kc.realm("zdslogic");
    UsersResource usersRessource = realmResource.users();

    // Create Keycloak user
    Response result = null;
    try {
        result = usersRessource.create(keycloakUser);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    if (result==null || result.getStatus() != 201) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't create Keycloak user.");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Keycloak user created.... verify in keycloak!");
    }

    return user;

}
```